# column filtering by name on a dataframe resulting from a merge with multilevel column names

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a trouble to filter column of a data frame that results from a merge between a basic dataframe and another coming from a groupby with multiple output columns.

Let me be more specific:

1) I construct my "strange" data frame: *df_analyzed*:

```
n_elements = 1000;
np.random.seed(1234);
X1 = np.random.randint(10,size=n_elements)*2;
X2 = np.random.normal(size=n_elements);
Y  = 4*X1+X2;
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':X1,'X2':X2,'Y':Y})
df_analyzed = df[['X1','Y']] .groupby('X1').agg([np.count_nonzero,np.mean,np.std]).rename(columns={'count_nonzero':'count','mean':'average'}).reset_index();
```

2) I construct my basic data frame: *df2*:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X1':np.array(range(10))*2,'Y_true':np.array(range(10))*2*4})
```

3) then I merge on *X1*:

```
 df2 = df2.merge(df_analyzed,on='X1', how='inner')
```

My problem now: how can I filter the column of *df2* by name?

The problem deals with the multilevel column names of *df_analyzed* that generates composed names with parentheses.

```
df2.columns
```

gives:

> Index([            'X1',       'Y_true_x',       ('X1', ''),   ('Y',
>   'count'),
>          ('Y', 'average'),     ('Y', 'std'),       'Y_true_y'],
>         dtype='object')

The point is that:

```
df2[['X1', ('Y', 'average')]]
```

does not work, whereas:

```
df2[['X1']]
```

and

```
df2[[  ('Y', 'average')]]
```

do work.

What is the trick? What is the best practice?

Thanks,

Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you get `MultiIndex` in columns.

You need define column `Y` for `agg` and then all working nice:

```
df_analyzed = (df.groupby('X1')['Y'] #<-define column
                .agg([np.count_nonzero,np.mean,np.std])
                .rename(columns={'count_nonzero':'count','mean':'average'})
                .reset_index())
print (df_analyzed)
   X1  count    average       std
0   0   93.0   0.060892  0.910723
1   2  107.0   8.227543  1.037363
2   4  107.0  15.860760  1.023521
3   6  108.0  23.882749  1.022283
4   8   97.0  31.887406  0.996574
5  10   98.0  40.162716  0.987292
6  12   89.0  48.109856  1.157019
7  14   95.0  56.199991  0.978952
8  16   90.0  63.932482  0.956221
9  18  116.0  71.967112  0.941378
```

EDIT:

If need select both columns of your original output need tuples:

```
print (df_analyzed[[('X1', ''), ('Y', 'average')]])
   X1          Y
         average
0   0   0.060892
1   2   8.227543
2   4  15.860760
3   6  23.882749
4   8  31.887406
5  10  40.162716
6  12  48.109856
7  14  56.199991
8  16  63.932482
9  18  71.967112
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem at the end. Is it the best practice? or is there no chance to filter by column names using something like `df2[['X1', ('Y', 'average')]]`?

Comment: I think the best is if columns are flatten.

Comment: I add solution for filtering.